# Error in running docx4j createhtml.java file

Tags: java, html, xml, docx4j

```
C:\Users\Agastheswar\Desktop\RESUME2.docx
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
16 [main] INFO org.docx4j.utils.Log4jConfigurator  - Since your log4j configuration (if any) was not found, docx4j has configured log4j automatically.
32 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context  - JAXB: RI not present.  Trying Java 6 implementation.
32 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context  - JAXB: Using Java 6 implementation.
32 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context  - loading Context jc
9813 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context  - loaded com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl .. loading others ..
10360 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context  - .. others loaded ..
10439 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager  - Detected WordProcessingML package 
10458 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /_rels/.rels
10458 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart  - unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart
10467 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /docProps/app.xml
10467 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsExtendedPart  - unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsExtendedPart
10474 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /docProps/core.xml
10474 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsCorePart  - unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsCorePart
10483 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/document.xml
10483 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart  - For MDP, unmarshall via binder
10748 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/_rels/document.xml.rels
10748 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart  - unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart
10751 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/fontTable.xml
10821 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
Warning: Xalan jar missing from classpath; xslt not supported
10823 [main] WARN org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Using default SAXParserFactory: null
10824 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/styles.xml
10850 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG  - Encountered (but not loading) hyperlink mailto:agastheswar@gmail.com
10851 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/numbering.xml
10886 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager  - Looking at extension 'xml
10887 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager  - Found content type 'application/xml' for /customXml/item1.xml
10887 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /customXml/item1.xml
10889 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /customXml/item1.xml
10890 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /customXml/_rels/item1.xml.rels
10890 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart  - unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart
10901 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /customXml/itemProps1.xml
10903 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/webSettings.xml
10906 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/settings.xml
10936 [main] WARN org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - [ERROR] : unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", local:"compatSetting"). Expected
10936 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - continuing (with possible element/attribute loss)
10939 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPart  - encountered unexpected content; pre-processing
11233 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Detected com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl, but require org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl. Ensure Xalan 2.7.0 is on your classpath!
11263 [main] WARN org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - [ERROR] : unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", local:"compatSetting"). Expected
11263 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - continuing (with possible element/attribute loss)
11264 [main] WARN org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - [ERROR] : unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", local:"compatSetting"). Expected
11264 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - continuing (with possible element/attribute loss)
11265 [main] WARN org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - [ERROR] : unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", local:"compatSetting"). Expected
11265 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - continuing (with possible element/attribute loss)
11266 [main] WARN org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - [ERROR] : unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", local:"compatSetting"). Expected
11266 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler  - continuing (with possible element/attribute loss)
11275 [main] WARN org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager  - DefaultPart used for part '/word/stylesWithEffects.xml' of content type 'application/vnd.ms-word.stylesWithEffects+xml'
11278 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/stylesWithEffects.xml
11296 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part  - /word/theme/theme1.xml
11296 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.ThemePart  - unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.ThemePart
11469 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.getCssForTableCells(reference, node-set)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.getCssForTableCells(reference, node-set)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11472 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.createBlockForPPr(reference, node-set, string, result-tree)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.createBlockForPPr(reference, node-set, string, result-tree)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11473 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.createBlockForRPr(reference, string, node-set, result-tree)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.createBlockForRPr(reference, string, node-set, result-tree)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11473 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.SdtWriter.toNode(reference, node-set, result-tree)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.SdtWriter.toNode(reference, node-set, result-tree)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11473 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.model.images.WordXmlPictureE20.createHtmlImgE20(reference, reference, node-type)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.model.images.WordXmlPictureE20.createHtmlImgE20(reference, reference, node-type)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11474 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11476 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.model.images.WordXmlPictureE10.createHtmlImgE10(reference, reference, node-type)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.model.images.WordXmlPictureE10.createHtmlImgE10(reference, reference, node-type)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11501 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11501 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11501 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11502 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11502 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.notImplemented(node-type, string)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
11502 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Could not compile stylesheet
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:733)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.<clinit>(HtmlExporterNG2.java:126)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:51)
13086 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/ALGER.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13102 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/BAUHS93.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13102 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/BERNHC.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13119 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/BROADW.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13134 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/CHILLER.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13165 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/ELEPHNTI.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13181 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/Gabriola.ttf (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13197 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/GIGI.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13212 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/HARLOWSI.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13212 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/HARNGTON.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13212 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/HATTEN.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13212 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/impact.ttf (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13228 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/ITCBLKAD.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13228 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/JOKERMAN.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13228 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/JUICE___.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13306 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/PLAYBILL.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13337 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/SNAP____.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13353 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/STENCIL.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13353 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/SWMacro.otf (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13353 [main] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts  - Aborting: file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/TEMPSITC.TTF (can't get EmbedFontInfo[] .. try deleting fop-fonts.cache?)
13415 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.StyleDefinitionsPart  - Style with name Normal, id 'Normal' is default paragraph style
13431 [main] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.StyleDefinitionsPart  - Style with name Default Paragraph Font, id 'DefaultParagraphFont' is default character style
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:763)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:723)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.html.HtmlExporterNG2.html(HtmlExporterNG2.java:269)
    at CreateHtml.main(CreateHtml.java:76)
```

Firstly coudnt fix the log file Next couldnt understand the errors and fix them
I used the following code:

```
public class CreateHtml extends AbstractSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws Exception {

        try {
            getInputFilePath(args);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            inputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sample-docs/word/sample-docx.xml";
        }
        System.out.println(inputfilepath);          

        boolean save = true;            


        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));

        AbstractHtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporterNG2();  

        HtmlSettings htmlSettings = new HtmlSettings();

        htmlSettings.setImageDirPath(inputfilepath + "_files"); 
        htmlSettings.setImageTargetUri(inputfilepath.substring(inputfilepath.lastIndexOf("/")+1) 
                + "_files");

        htmlSettings.setUserBodyTop("<H1>TOP!</H1>");
        htmlSettings.setUserBodyTail("<H1>TAIL!</H1>");



        SdtWriter.registerTagHandler(Containerization.TAG_BORDERS, new TagSingleBox() );
        SdtWriter.registerTagHandler(Containerization.TAG_SHADING, new TagSingleBox() );

        OutputStream os; 
        if (save) {
            os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(inputfilepath + ".html");
        } else {
            os = System.out;

        }

        javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(os);
        exporter.html(wordMLPackage, result, htmlSettings);
        if (save) {
            System.out.println("Saved: " + inputfilepath + ".html using " +  exporter.getClass().getName() );
        }

    }
}
```

This was the code i used !!! i have given the input file a docx file from my desktop

Answer (score 3):

From the log you provided:

```
10821 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
Warning: Xalan jar missing from classpath; xslt not supported
10823 [main] WARN org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - Using default SAXParserFactory: null
```

Try adding Xalan to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks it worked !!!but i cant convert doc files as they dont have the xml content what changes in the code should i make so that it works both for doc and docx???

Comment: docx4j is a solution (as implied by its name) that is designed for the newer XML-based .docx file format. It won't work on the older binary .doc file format.